# How to generate a tensor representing, for each pair of rows in a matrix, whether elements at the same position both = 1?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, linear-algebra

I'm trying to compare every row in a matrix to every other row in the same matrix, yielding, for each pair, a row showing whether each element of those two rows both equal 1.

Example: if I have this matrix as input:

```
[[1,0,1],
 [0,1,1],
 [0,0,0]]
```

I'd want to get this tensor:

```
[[[1,0,1],
  [0,0,1],
  [0,0,0]],
 [[0,0,1],
  [0,1,1]
  [0,0,0]],
 [[0,0,0],
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0]]]
```

Alternatively, if it's easier, my eventual goal is to reduce this tensor down to a matrix where each row represents whether ANY elements in a pair of rows from the original matrix both =1. So, the tensor above would get reduced to:

```
[[1,1,0],
 [1,1,0],
 [0,0,0]]
```

If it's easier to go straight to that without going through the intermediate tensor, let me know.

Comment: I didn't get how the last matrix is computed. Could you explain why the item `(0, 1)` is equal to `1`?

Comment: Idea there is item (0,1) represents whether row 0 and row 1 have at least 1 element where both rows are 1. Since the last element in row 0 is 1 and the last element in row 1 is also 1, this item at (0,1) is 1. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh, so the pair of rows is based on the position of the element. I get it now. So, ultimately, this last matrix will always be symmetric, right?

Comment: yes, that's right. Last one must be symmetric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat a partial answer, but it solves the first step which seems to be the question at hand:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,0,1],
              [0,1,1],
              [0,0,0]])

output = x * np.repeat(x[:, np.newaxis, :], 3, axis=1)

output
# array([[[1, 0, 1],
#         [0, 0, 1],
#         [0, 0, 0]],

#        [[0, 0, 1],
#         [0, 1, 1],
#         [0, 0, 0]],

#        [[0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0]]])
```

In PyTorch, it would be:

```py
import torch

x = torch.tensor([[1,0,1],
                  [0,1,1],
                  [0,0,0]])

output = x * x.unsqueeze(1).repeat_interleave(3, dim=1)
```